# How to match original length of values after smoothing curve using UnivariateSpline

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I have a dataset that is filled with noise. I did some curve interpolation using scipy UnivariateSpline but after that the length of original and interpolated curve does not match anymore.
[image]

I applied this code below.

```
x = df[df.unit==1].cycles
y = df[df.unit==1].S8

from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import numpy as np

s = UnivariateSpline(df[df.unit==1].cycles, df[df.unit==1].S8, s=5)
xs = np.linspace(0, len(y))
ys = s(xs)

print(len(x),len(y))
> 192,192

print(len(xs),len(ys))
> 50,50
```

We can see that the length of the original data is 192 but after interpolation it is just 50. I want to return the new data into the dataframe. Doing it as it is returns a `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` so how do I do this? Thank you!

**================ UPDATE ==================**

We can simply change the linspace into arange and set the value into the desired length

```
s = UnivariateSpline(df[df.unit==1].cycles, df[df.unit==1].S8, s=5)
xs = np.arange(0, len(y))
ys = s(xs)

print(len(xs),len(ys))
> 192,192
```

Comment: `np.linspace` generates 50 evenly spaced points by default, maybe you want to use `np.arange` or change `num` parameter to `len(y)`

Comment: @FBruzzesi you're a livesaver! Do you mind , how do I replace the old values with the new ones back into the dataframe?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here. If you want to add the spline values corresponding to `x` you can just do `df['S8_spline'] = s(x)`. However I am afraid that this should not work as the length of `x` is less than the length of the dataframe as you are subsetting. I can code some workaround as an answer if needed.